# When designing a web application with Vue.js and ASP.NET Core, is ASP.NET solely for the API?

Tags: design, web-development, web-api, asp.net-mvc-web-api, asp.net-core

When creating a web application from scratch with ASP.NET MVC Core (using Visual Studio 2017) and using Vue.js, is the MVC Core part of the application solely for the API?  What other function would it have other than allowing Visual Studio to use the Task Runner?

Update:  When I create an application with Vue using Visual Studio, and I want to use Core, is the design method to use Vue as the presentation and VS solely as the backend?  I don't need to worry abour Razor or anything else, is that right?

Comment: Could you make it some more clear points on it? It is little bit confused i.e. what do you mean by MVC Core? What do you mean by what other function? Thank you.

Comment: @IPKaal I added an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to build Web Application using .Net Core and Vue.js and you do not want to use MVC Razor view. IF that is the case, .Net Core is the back-end (Server side) framework where you can create your controller and infrastracture and you can still use Entity Framework Core for your database layer as ORM whereas Vue.js can be your presentation layer.

Yes, that is right if you use Vue or angular for your presenation layer you do not need to use MVC Razor view. But remember you need to create api endpoints i.e. you can use WebApi 2 for your service layer.

In nutshell, Vue.js will be your presentation layer, Entity Framework Core will be your database layer (ORM), WebApi 2 will be your service layer and .Net Core is your serverside platform and Visual Studio (VS) is IDE.